# How to print a CSV by row instead of column?

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to print the first 3 columns of a CSV in PHP and when each row is clicked, it will redirect to another page displaying more information from that row.

I've done this successfully, however my issue is that the table is printed column first instead of row first, so the id is per column instead of row. Is there anyway of changing this to print row first but still restrict it to 3 columns?

```
<?php
    $libraryData = fopen("../data/libraryData.csv", "r");

    echo '<div class="container" id="table_container">';
    echo '<table class="table table-sm table-responsive table-bordered table-striped pd-0" id="csvTable">';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($libraryData, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            echo '<td><a href="display.php?row=' . $i . '">' . htmlspecialchars($data[$i]) . '</a </td>';

      }
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    fclose($libraryData);

?>
```

Comment: Check the nesting of the loop - surely, you don't want to generate IDs from 0 to 2 **within a single line from the CSV file**

Comment: Every call to `fgetcsv` will get you one row. You need to keep the count of the rows within your while loop. `$r = 0; while ( fgetcsv..) { ... ?row=$r">; ...; $r++ }`

Comment: Not really clear what your probelm is, can you show us an example of say 2 rows from the csv AND the resulting HTML you want from those rows

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to display the first three columns of each row as links in a table, where clicking on each link redirects to another page (display.php) with more information from that specific row. However, you've set the link () to include a fixed value for the row parameter **(?row=' . $i . ')** in the loop, which results in the same value for all links.

In order to fix this, you need to pass the actual row index dynamically. You can modify the link to include the row index in the URL.

Update your code as follow:

```
  <?php
    $libraryData = fopen("../data/libraryData.csv", "r");

    echo '<div class="container" id="table_container">';
    echo '<table class="table table-sm table-responsive table-bordered table-striped pd-0" id="csvTable">';
    
    // Initialize row index
    $rowIndex = 0; 
    
    while (($data = fgetcsv($libraryData, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo '<tr>';
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            // Pass the row index dynamically in the link
            echo '<td><a href="display.php?row=' . $rowIndex . '">' . htmlspecialchars($data[$i]) . '</a></td>';
        }
        
        echo '</tr>';
        
        // Increment row index for the next row
        $rowIndex++; 
    }
    
    echo '</table>';
    fclose($libraryData);
?>
```